# Get the id of a model object which is FK of another model object django

Tags: django, python-class

I have a model named WarehouseProduct, which has a field warehouse_id which is FK of Warehouse model, and i need to get that warehouse_id, so that it would return the id of that FK Warehouse. I tried using:

```
def __int__(self):
    return self.id
```

which returns WareHouse object (6), and another way:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

which returns id, but the type is Warehouse so i can't convert it to `int` for further usage.

Comment: warehouse_id.id always return a int when the primary key of warehouse is default or a integer-like field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my `warehouse_id` FK is a model instance, I need to get this FK's id, not itself, and when I use this way, it doesn't matter what magic method do I use:

`Object.warehouse_id.id` works best.

Answer (score 1):

You can get ant id by the values() and first() function in views

```
WarehouseProduct.objects.values('warehouse_id')
```

it will return all objects ids(only)
By filter WarehouseProduct you get the specific id

```
WarehouseProduct.objects.filter(WarehouseProduct_filed == Value you enter ).first()
```